# Passing values from parent pipeline to child pipeline in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm pretty sure this is simple, but I can't seem to find this anywhere. I created a parameter in a parent pipeline (say the pipeline name is TestParent)  in data factory:

[image]
This parent pipeline invokes a child pipeline. I want to reference this parameter in the child pipeline. What is the syntax to get the value of this parameter from the parent in the child?

Answer (score 2):

OK I finally got this to work:

I completely removed the parameter from the parent pipeline. In the child pipeline (which is called HubMaster) we create a parameter called MasterBatchId:

[image]

In the parent pipeline I created an [Execute pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-execute-pipeline-activity) node called EP_HubMaster that calls a child pipeline called HubMaster. In order to populate the child pipeline parameter MasterBatchId at run time, we need to edit the JSON of the parent pipeline to look like this:

```
{
"name": "TestParent",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "EP_HubMaster",
            "type": "ExecutePipeline",
            "typeProperties": {
                "pipeline": {
                    "referenceName": "HubMaster",
                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                },
                "parameters": {
                    "MasterBatchId": {
                        "value": "@pipeline().RunId",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "folder": {
        "name": "Master"
    }
},
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}
```

You can see that we pass the `@pipeline().RunId` from the parent (which was the original intent) to the input parameter of `MasterBatchId` in the child pipeline.

Comment: Which means you need to edit the JSON file every time while you run it? How is it going to work in a CI/CD fashion?